# Vue 3 - Component is not loaded or rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have following component:

```
<script setup>

import {defineProps, ref, watch} from "vue";
import ProductsComponent from '@/components/Products.vue'
import OrdersComponent from '@/components/Orders.vue'
import {useTableOrderStore} from "@/store/tableOrder";

const tableOrderStore = useTableOrderStore()

const props = defineProps({
  orderID: {
    type: Number
  },
  tableID: {
    type: Number
  },
  tableName: {
    type: String
  }
})

let orders = ref([])

watch(props, (newProp, oldProp) => {
  orders = tableOrderStore.tableOrders

  console.log(orders)
})

</script>
<template>
  <products-component :tableName="tableName"></products-component>
  <orders-component v-for="order in orders" :order="order" :key="order.id"></orders-component>
</template>
```

And **OrdersComponent** which is loaded in this component:

```
<script setup>

import {watch} from "vue";

let props = defineProps({
  order: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
})

watch(props, (newProp, oldProp) => {
  console.log(newProp)
})

console.log(12333)

</script>

<template>
  <div class="row">
    {{ order }}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, expedita?
  </div>
</template>
```

When the main component is shown, **ProductsComponent** is loaded and shown, but OrdersComponent is not. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component is not rendered because the array `orders` is still empty and the watcher to update it is not working properly which should be written by returning props from callback and adding other options (`immediate` and `deep`):

```js
let orders = ref([])

watch(()=>props, (newProp, oldProp) => {
  orders.value = tableOrderStore.tableOrders

  console.log(orders.value)
},{
immediate:true,
deep:true //since props are an object
})
```